# Rails select_box with non model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have problem with select boxes in rails. I have model Page, and in form for it I want to build select box with 2 values that i wll define that are not model attributes. I want this strange thing to can hide with jquery some parts of my form. Is there any way to do it with simple_form or rails form helpers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `select_tag` helper (see [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)):

```
select_tag "credit_card", options_for_select([ "VISA", "MasterCard" ], "MasterCard")
```